# How To combine Rspec command line switches (i.e. tags & full search)

Tags: rspec

Is it possible to combine in Rspec the command line options for full-text search and for tags? Like `rspec spec -e User -t buggy` etc.
It always just does one if I just put it after each other - is there a trick or workaround?

(Output
`Run options: include {:full_description=>/selftest/}?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the moment it's just not possible and one has to wait for a future release of rspec